# How to use $stdout and $stdin with unix pipes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, awk, pipe, stdout, stdin

I can create a ruby executable like this (dummy example):

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env ruby
    puts %x[awk ''{print toupper($1)}'' #{STDIN} ]
' > pipes.rb
chmod +x pipes.rb
```

Then I can use this file other unix tools:

```
echo "a\nb\nc\nd" | ./pipes.rb | head -n2
# A
# B
```

But if I need to extend the dummy example with another call to awk, it doesn't work:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env ruby
    puts %x[awk ''{print toupper($1)}'' #{STDIN} | awk ''{ \
    print tolower($1) \
}'']
' >! pipes2.rb
chmod +x pipes2.rb
echo "a\nb\nc\nd" | ./pipes2.rb | head -n2
# A
# B
# it should be: "a\nb"
```

The problem is that `STDIN` gets stringified as something like: `#<IO:0x007fe18406ac58>` and the hash gets interpreted as a comment, so the second `awk` statement gets ignored (but for some reason the `head` command still returns two lines):

```
awk '{print toupper($1)}' #<IO:0x007fe18406ac58> | awk '{ print tolower($1)}'
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this (escaping the `STDIN` reference?). This is the simplest reproducible example I could come up with. On my real script I allow multiple input sources (standard input or a file argument). The non-negotiable requirement is that the `awk` code needs a reference to the input, I can't just process it line-by-line in Ruby.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Following @tadman's suggestion, I've done this and it works!:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "open3"
Open3.popen3("awk '{print toupper($1)}'") do |cmd_in, cmd_out, cmd_err|
    cmd_in.write(STDIN.read)
    cmd_in.close
    Open3.popen3("awk '{print tolower($1)}'") do |cmd_in2, cmd_out2, cmd_err2|
        cmd_in2.write(cmd_out.read)
        cmd_in2.close
        puts cmd_out2.read    
    end
end


echo "aAA\nbBB\ncCC\ndDD" | ./pipes2.rb | head -n2
# aaa
# bbb
```

Is there a way to refactor this?

Comment: It's a little unusual to see `$stdin` and `$stdout` used in production Ruby code, they're global variables inspired by Perl. Most of the time you'll see `STDIN` and `STDOUT` used. `STDOUT.puts` is also redundant since `puts` goes to `STDOUT` by default.

Comment: ok, I can use  `STDIN` and `puts`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're supplying `$stdin` directly instead of doing anything with it. That's why Ruby is rendering it as a raw object. It's a filehandle, unless you exercise a method on it, not raw data.

What you want is to fetch all content from that filehandle:

```
$stdin.read
```

If you're going to use Ruby, there's no reason to use `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts STDIN.read.upcase
```

If you want the newlines preserved as `"\n"`, then do this:

```
puts STDIN.read.upcase.inspect
```

If you're committed to using an external command:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("awk '{print toupper($1)}'") do |cmd_in, cmd_out, cmd_err|
  # Read from our STDIN and push through to the command's STDIN
  cmd_in.write(STDIN.read)

  # Close STDIN on the command to tell it we're finished writing.
  cmd_in.close

  # Read result from command's STDOUT and write to our STDOUT
  puts cmd_out.read.inspect
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to use awk. The upcase/downcase is just an example

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to use `awk`? There's nothing it can do that Ruby can't, plus translating from `awk` to Ruby is usually pretty simple. If you do need to use external commands, [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) is the way to do it, giving you full control over input and output.

Comment: That looks interesting, is there a way to combine multiple commands (like the two awk calls above)?

Comment: Of course, you can keep changing in->in, out->out as necessary, even nesting them if required.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found an even simpler way

```
require "open3"
Open3.pipeline(
    ["awk '{print toupper($1)}'"],
    ["awk '{print tolower($1)}'"], 
:in => STDIN) # this is redundant, but I might want to change :in in the future
```